# Remove Site Collections with CSOM in SharePoint 2016 on-premise

Tags: csom, sharepoint-on-prem

According to this Blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/12/04/sharepoint-tenant-csom-object-support-in-sharepoint-2013-and-2016/ 
it should be possible to remove Site Collections by using CSOM.

When executing the following code, I am getting an access denied error:

```
var tenant = new Tenant(adminContext);
tenant.RemoveSite(testSite);
adminContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

My account has farm admin permissions.

In the Blog Post Vesa talks about specific permissions without mentioning the specific permissions:

> Notice also that some of the supported methods do require specific
>   permissions for the account used for the operations, if you do not use
>   oAuth for granting the needed permissions in your on-premises
>   deployment.

I am wondering what those special permission may be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably late answer, in our case, we are using shared hosted app to gain permissions. The site collection where our app is installed tenant admin rights are enabled. Otherwise you'll be unable to create or delete site collection.